# LINQ LEFT JOIN where clause not working

Tags: c#, linq

I need to return a list of all the events and any rsvps a user may have for an event. However, regardless of the username I pass, It returns every single rsvp. My linq Query ->

```
   return (from events in this._context.Context.Events
           join rsvps in (this._context.Context.RSVPs
                          .Where(o=> o.UserName == userName))
           on events equals rsvps.Event into re
           from rsvps in re.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select events);
```

Relationship is
    Events.EventID = RSVPs.EventID

Comment: Something seems wrong here - specifically the part `on events equals rsvps.Event` A rewrite may be necessary. What field relates the Events table to RSVPs table?

Comment: RSVPs.EventID = events.EventID

Comment: @user1106741 write `on events.EventID equals rsvps.EventID into re`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
from e in _context.Context.Events
join r in _context.Context.RSVPs.Where(o => o.UserName == userName)
    on e.EventID equals r.EventID into g
select new {
    Event = e,
    Rsvps = g
};
```

Comment: I don't want to create an anonymous type

Comment: @user1106741 then use navigation property of event

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
return (from events in this._context.Context.Events
        join rsvps in this._context.Context.RSVPs
        on events.EventIDequals equals rsvps.EventID into re
        from c in re.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where c.UserName == userName
        select new {events,rsvps});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter the RSVPs property of your Events in-place, then I guess you probably could do use something like

```
var events = _context.Context.Events;

foreach(var event in events)
{
    // Assuming the property is named RSVPs
    event.RSVPs = event.RSVPs.Where(o => o.UserName.Equals(userName));
}

return events;
```

I wouldn't consider it that neat though.