# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause in LINQ Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
model.ListManagerReviewerMapping = (from a in wallet.OM_Employee 
                                    join m in wallet.APPR_ManagerMapping 
                                    on a.AssociateId equals m.AssociateId
                                    where m.ManagerId==Context.UserId.Value **into** MM 
                                    from leftjoinresult in M.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                                    where a.CompanyId == Context.CompanyId && (a.TermStatus == "L" || a.SeparationDate > DateTime.Today) 
                                    select new ManagerAndReviewerMappingModel.ManagerAndReviewerMapping() 
                                    { 
                                        Photo = (photoUrl + "?AssociateCode=" + a.AssociateCode), 
                                        AssociateId = a.AssociateId,
                                        AssociateCode = a.AssociateCode,
                                        AssociateName = a.AssociateName
                                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Please format your code in a readable manner. Hint: Indent by 4 spaces. And what is actually the problem or question?

Comment: What is the Question or problem?

Comment: **into** get error from A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause in LINQ Query

Comment: What do you mean by `**into** MM` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Where` extension method for first query, as the query uses left join with `DefaultIfEmpty` (note that you can't use `into` after `where` clause since `where` must be followed with `select` to finish the query):

```
model.ListManagerReviewerMapping = (from a in wallet.OM_Employee 
                                    join m in wallet.APPR_ManagerMapping.Where(x => x.ManagerId == Context.UserId.Value)
                                    on a.AssociateId equals m.AssociateId into MM 

                                    from leftjoinresult in MM.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                                    where a.CompanyId == Context.CompanyId && (a.TermStatus == "L" || a.SeparationDate > DateTime.Today) 
                                    select new ManagerAndReviewerMappingModel.ManagerAndReviewerMapping() 
                                    { 
                                        Photo = (photoUrl + "?AssociateCode=" + a.AssociateCode), 
                                        AssociateId = a.AssociateId,
                                        AssociateCode = a.AssociateCode,
                                        AssociateName = a.AssociateName
                                    }).ToList();
```

Similar issues:

[LINQ LEFT JOIN where clause not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082767/linq-left-join-where-clause-not-working)

[LINQ Left Join And Right Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497086/linq-left-join-and-right-join)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Remove brackets and .ToList();
model.ListManagerReviewerMapping = from a in wallet.OM_Employee 
                                join m in wallet.APPR_ManagerMapping 
                                on a.AssociateId equals m.AssociateId
                                where m.ManagerId==Context.UserId.Value **into** MM 
                                from leftjoinresult in M.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                                where a.CompanyId == Context.CompanyId && (a.TermStatus == "L" || a.SeparationDate > DateTime.Today) 
                                select new ManagerAndReviewerMappingModel.ManagerAndReviewerMapping() 
                                { 
                                    Photo = (photoUrl + "?AssociateCode=" + a.AssociateCode), 
                                    AssociateId = a.AssociateId,
                                    AssociateCode = a.AssociateCode,
                                    AssociateName = a.AssociateName
                                };
```