# Left/outer join with linq on c# with where condition clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, left-join, asp.net-core-2.0

I have 2 tables that I need to join in a query. 
The first table is the Entries table which contain certain events such as Dance, Speak, Sing, Play, etc.

```
Id|Name  
   1|Dance  
   2|Sing  
   3|Speak  
   4|Play  
   5| etc.
```

The other table contains userEntries which indicates each user's score on each of the events

```
Id| UserId|EntryId|Score

 1|898128 | 1     |200

 2|827329 | 2     |120

 3|898128 | 2     |100
```

Now I want a linq query to first of all get all the entries and then get the scores for a given user for the entries retunining null for the entry score whete the user has noscore

Example 
for user 898128, I want to see something like this

Dance:200,Speak:null,Sing:120 from the result

I have tried the following linq query and I get an empty result

```
var userScores = 
(from e in db.Entries join se in db.UserEntries
on e.Id equals se.EntryId                                           
into ese from se in 
ese.DefaultIfEmpty()
where se.UserId == "898128"
select new 
{
EntryLabel=e.Label,
EntryValue=se.ValueAmount,
}).ToList();

ViewData["userScores "] = userScores;
```

I am running on ASP.NET core 2.0, entity framework core on a Windows 10 machine with Visual Studio 2017 15.6.3

I will appreciate any guide to getting the query right to give me an outer join so I can get all the entries for each user even where the user does not have any score.

Please note that this is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq) errorneously marked by [@Mahmoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4359687/mahmoud) as its duplicate. The difference lies in the presence of the WHERE condition clause.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082767/linq-left-join-where-clause-not-working). From there, I realized that the position of the where clause is the problem. See the working code revision below

```
var userScores = 
(from e in db.Entries join se in db.UserEntries.Where(o => o.UserId == 
"898128" 
on e.Id equals se.EntryId                                           
into ese from se in 
ese.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
EntryLabel=e.Label,
EntryValue=se.ValueAmount,
}).ToList();

ViewData["userScores "] = userScores;
```

Thank you [@Hazarath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9405863/hazarath-chillara) for your guide

Comment: This generates subquery with the join so this is the correct solution.
Use solution from @user9405863

Comment: it doesn't generate "join with where condition clause". It generate a subquery

Comment: @MohammadNikravan do you have an example of one that generates a join query?

Comment: @Josh you can achieve the join with clause by "on new {key1,key2} equals {value1, value2}", but i couldn't find how to generate a join with complex clause like ".. on id1 = id2 and createdTime>x)

Answer (score 4):

Try this query. it should fix your issue.

```
 var userScores =(from e in db.Entries
                 join se in db.UserEntries on e.Id equals se.EntryId into ese
                 from nullse in ese.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where (nullse==nulll ||(nullse!=null && nullse.UserId == "898128"))
                 select new
                 {
                    EntryLabel = e.Name,
                    EntryValue = nullse != null ? nullse.ValueAmount:"null"
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you @Hazarath for your efforts but I'm still getting empty result when I add this line 

where (nullse!=null && nullse.UserId == "898128")

to it. Could this line be causing the system to run an inner join?

Comment: @Josh : updated answer ..try that and let me know..as we are doing  outer join. checking null value for userId comparison.

Comment: it doesn't generate "join with where condition clause"